# How to find currently running code in Node.js

Tags: node.js, v8

I have a Node.js/Express web application which sometimes slow response. After checked the system CPU and memory I found it consumed ~80% CPU and memory, and then 1 - 2 minutes later they down to ~10%.

I think this was because my Node.js is running some codes in user-thread, for example mapping objects retrieved from database.

It's a little bit hard to review the code of my application to figure out where the bad code was. So I would like to know is there any tool or `npm` module I can use to write down the code Node.js is running when an API request was processed longer than, for example 5 seconds.

I tried `v8-profiler` but it seems that it only support to start profiling and then stop, but not capture what code is running at that moment.

Answer (score 0):

use visual studio code for debuging your nodejs code

https://code.visualstudio.com/b?utm_expid=101350005-24.YOq70TI1QcW9kAbMwmhePg.1&utm_referrer=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com.pk%2F